# And condition in neo4j cypher query doesn't work

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created a neo4j database with trains and stations. Each train stops at(this is the relationship) a station. I have written below cypher query and got the attached response

```
match  (train:Train)-[:STOP_AT]->(station:Station)
where station.id='101' or station.id='65'
return train,station;
```

[image]
this gives me all the trains which stop at station id='101' or '65'.
But when I run the below cypher to get all the trains which stop at id='101' and '65' I got nothing

```
match  (train:Train)-[:STOP_AT]->(station:Station)
where station.id='101' and station.id='65'
return train,station;
```

This is a simple cypher but I can't find the problem of the query. Can someone help me find out the problem?

Comment: This query works fine.
match  (train:Train)-[:STOP_AT]->(:Station{id:'65'})
where (train)-[:STOP_AT]->(:Station{id:'101'})
return train;
I have no idea why first cypher didn't work for me

Comment: That logic won't work, there is no single node where its property is simultaneously two different values. You may want to take a look at this knowledge base article on [performing match intersection](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/), that will let you perform the kind of match you want to an arbitrary number of stations given a list of their ids.

Comment: @InverseFalcon thank for the solution. That made a sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this query :

```
match  (train:Train)-[:STOP_AT]->(station:Station)
where station.id='101' and station.id='65'
return train,station;
```

you are searching a station that has at the same time the id `101` & `65`. So it's not possible and the result is emtpy.

What you want is to find a train that stop at two stations. So this is the query :

```
MATCH  
  (train:Train)-[:STOP_AT]->(station1:Station),
  (train)-[:STOP_AT]->(station2:Station)
WHERE 
  station1.id='101' AND
  station2.id='65'
RETURN train,station;
```